Given an undirected weighted graph, how to find the minimum cost so that I can start from any node and traverse all other nodes that is in the graph?
Title: Finding the Maximum of Minimum Costs in a Modified Kruskal's Algorithm
Question:
I'm working on a graph problem where I need to find the maximum of the minimum costs starting from a specific node x and traversing all other nodes in the graph. Essentially, I want to modify Kruskal's algorithm to achieve this.
Here's how I'm thinking of approaching it, but I need guidance on the implementation:
Understand the Problem:
I want to build a spanning tree that includes node x and minimizes the cost of the most expensive edge in the tree.
Modify Kruskal's Algorithm:
Start with node x instead of the first edge.
Sort all edges in non-decreasing order of weight.
Iterate through the sorted edges, adding them to the spanning tree if they don't create a cycle and connecting a new node to the tree.
Implementation Details:
I'll need a data structure to represent the graph and its edges.
Efficient cycle detection, possibly using a Union-Find data structure.
Tracking the maximum of the minimum costs during the algorithm's execution.
Could someone provide a more detailed implementation or guide me on how to modify Kruskal's algorithm for this specific problem? Any insights, code snippets, or algorithmic pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Does this answer your question? Given an undirected weighted graph, how to find the minimum cost so that I can start from any node and traverse all other nodes in the graph?

Do not post duplicate questions.  Edit your original question so that it is acceptable.
